# Debian APT unable to install any package

Tags: linux, debian, apt, xfce

I am running Debian 9 with XFCE4 on Dell XPS 15 (9560). Recently I ran into trouble with apt. If I try to run anything using apt-get install, the following always return:

```
william@debian:~$ sudo apt-get install vim
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vim : Depends: vim-common (= 2:7.4.488-7+deb8u3) but 2:8.0.0197-4+deb9u1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried running `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade`, `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, `sudo apt-get clean`, and etc, etc.

Some of them return messages like this:

```
william@debian:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian jessie InRelease
Hit:2 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian jessie Release
Reading package lists... Done

william@debian:~$ sudo apt-get install upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package upgrade

william@debian:~$ sudo apt-get install dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dist-upgrade
```

Please help and thanks a lot :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Sorry I’m pretty new to stack overflow. Should I flag it for migration?

Comment: You can flag the question and ask the moderators move it so you don't have to delete it on one site and create it on another site. It also resets the question's score. For whatever reasons, the Stack Exchange network does not allow you to migrate it yourself. Also see [Author initiated migration to other SE sites?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851)

Comment: Sorry Jeff, it seems like I don't have the flagging privilege yet. Is there another way to migrate this thread besides deleting it?

Comment: No need to apologize. People do it all the time. It is the reason I use that message. The message tries to explain what Stack Overflow is for, and tries to point you in the right direction. [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) is very good site. I frequently use it (so I eat my own dog food).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your sources.list file......
Use terminal and open using permission

$ sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list

Paste the links here , you can find them on internet

Or paste these  :

deb  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
deb-src  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main

deb  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main
deb-src  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main

Thanku for asking amd sorry if im wrong somewhere

Comment: Thanks.. The example source.list on debian.org worked. BTW I'm running xfce so there's no gedit....

Comment: Glad to help (: